# Scaling of smart diagram?

Tags: margins

I have drawn a smart diagram, but when I compile it exceeds the page margin. Please guide me through this. if possible to have that in two lines is also helpful. my code is

```
%%%<
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{5pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{10pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>



\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Material sources for system,
  Input conditioning of system, sub-system model, Material Source for second system, first Output/second system Input condition,system Synthesis sub-system, system Synthesis Output condition}
\end{document}\\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use --

```
\scalebox{0.7}{
    \smartdiagram[...]{.....}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{5pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{10pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>



\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
    \smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true}
    \scalebox{0.7}{
    \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Material sources for system,
        Input conditioning of system, sub-system model, Material Source for second system, first Output/second system Input condition,system Synthesis sub-system, system Synthesis Output condition}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @ js bibra. Is it possible to write it in two lines, I mean after Material Source for second system putting a down arrow and contunuing the other blocks from right to left??

Comment: off course its possible  --please have a look at the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Quick trick, without reducing the size of the diagram. By shifting the diagram to the left with `\hspace{-3.5cm}`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{5pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{10pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>


\usepackage{showframe}% <-- To see the margins of the page
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true}
\hspace{-3.5cm}\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Material sources for system,
  Input conditioning of system, sub-system model, Material Source for second system, first Output/second system Input condition,system Synthesis sub-system, system Synthesis Output condition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `adjustbox` environment from the [`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox?lang=en) package which automatically scales the diagram to fit within `\textwidth`. I also added the `module minimum height=3.5cm` option to make all boxes the same height.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{5pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{10pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      % Added!

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width = \textwidth}
        \smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true, module minimum height=3.5cm}
        \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{
            Material sources for system,
            Input conditioning of system,
            sub-system model,
            Material Source for second system,
            first Output/ second system Input condition,
            system Synthesis sub-system,
            system Synthesis Output condition
        }
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```